# Makeshift wetsuit?

Tags: biology, medicine

Might make more sense to ask this in a skin-diving discussion, but... would something like motorcycle leathers hold up to water well enough to function as a wet suit, trapping a layer of warm water and permitting the wearer to survive in water temperatures that would otherwise be lethal?

(Not that I have a plot immediately in mind; the image just occurred to me and got me wondering why it wouldn't work.)

Answer (score 1):

Waterproofing isn't the only issue here. To trap warm water, the material has to insulate well. While I couldn't find the number for wet leather, dry leather has three times the thermal conductivity of neoprene, the material most wetsuits are made of - meaning it would lose heat three times as fast. You could counter this by having the leather layer be three times as thick. Of course, this only works if you have a complete bodysuit made of thick waterproofed leather - doable, but probably not common enough to count as "makeshift".

Comment: And the layer of water trapped by a wetsuit is very thin, leathers wouldn't fit like that, and tend to expand when wet anyway.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like by the time it's thick enough and waterproofed enough it wouldn't be cycle leathers any more. Maybe OK as a primitive attempt at diving suit, but less effective than I hoped even if made for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Leathers would work ok for trapping heat, but they'd also absorb a lot of water, making them very heavy. But if the water temps are in the lethal range, no wet suit would keep you alive. You'd need a dry suit, to actually keep the water out of the core. Without a purpose built suit, even if you survived you'd lose the extremities.

If the temperatures were more reasonable, say hypothermia inducing, but not frost byte causing, the leathers could be a "state of the art" set for cold weather riding, combining materials in layers for for wicking moisture (dry weave, coolmax, etc.), a thermal layer, with a water resistant coating. Combined with gloves and boots, you'd have a decent makeshift suit to increase survivability.  Of course all of that comes with weight, albeit slight.

If the motorcyclist was carrying a pack of some type, this could aid in buoyancy, offsetting the weight of the leathers and boots.  In such a scenario, with such a set of leathers, the feasability of survivability would be great enough to suspend disbelief.

Comment: Good point; I should change that to extending survival in more reasonable temps. _Very_ good point about absorption;  that's one of the places O suspected the idea might fail.